# purpose of AnonymousAuthenticationProvider in default spring-security conficuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have sample usage case of spring security:

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <sec:anonymous username="lolka"/>
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="adminpassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="user" password="userpassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

In this sample configuration are created `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` which handle anon users and provade their with my principal name: `lolka`. Genarating of this filter happend in `AuthenticationConfigBuilder.createAnonymousFilter`. If [open code of that method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/3.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/config/http/AuthenticationConfigBuilder.java#AuthenticationConfigBuilder.createAnonymousFilter%28%29), we can also find, that there is also created AnonymousAuthenticationProvider which is assigned to `anonymousProviderRef`, so that way this authenticationProvader **should** exist in list of my auth prividers, but if i get list of auth providers in runtime, there is only `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, which is created from `sec:authentication-manager` tag.

There is my code for getting auth providers in runtime:
@Autowired 
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    Object bean = applicationContext.getBean("authenticationManager");
    log.info("authenticationManager:{}",bean);
    ProviderManager vefified = (ProviderManager) bean;
    log.info("providers:{}",vefified.getProviders());


    try {
        Field ff = vefified.getClass().getDeclaredField("parent"); 
        ff.setAccessible(true);
        Object parentObj = ff.get(vefified);
        if(ProviderManager.class.isInstance(parentObj)){
            log.info("parent is instance of ProviderManager:{}", parentObj.getClass().getSimpleName());
            ProviderManager verifyedParent = (ProviderManager)parentObj;
            log.info("parent providers list:{}", verifyedParent.getProviders());
        } else {
            log.info("parent is NOT instance of ProviderManager:{}", parentObj);
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AnonymousAuthenticationProvider anonProvider = applicationContext.getBean(AnonymousAuthenticationProvider.class);
    log.info("AnonymousAuthenticationProvider:{}",anonProvider);

}
```

And there is output:

```
INFO (Main.java:35) authenticationManager:org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager@1566060
INFO (Main.java:37) providers:[org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@1d1695e]
INFO (Main.java:49) parent is NOT instance of ProviderManager:null
INFO (Main.java:56) AnonymousAuthenticationProvider:org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider@187d27e
```

So my questions are:

1. What is purpose of AnonymousAuthenticationProvider, if it is used at all?
2. Why AnonymousAuthenticationProvider is exist in runtime, but is not present in List in working `authenticationManager` ?

Spring version is: 3.2.4.RELEASE
Spring security version is: 3.1.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually another internal `ProviderManager` instance created for each filter chain you create with `<http>` and the anonymous provider is in there. The "parent" `AuthenticationManager` is the one you declare using the namespace and which contains the "real" authentication providers.

The `AnonymousAuthenticationProvider` doesn't really do anything useful. I'd just regard it as mostly a design legacy and not something you need to worry about. If it wasn't there, nothing would handle this token type and the `AuthenticationManager` would raise a [`ProviderNotFoundException`](https://github.com/tekul/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.java#L196).